# How to ingest List of entities programatically using C# .Net in Azure Data Explorer database table?

Tags: c#, azure-data-explorer

How to ingest/import the list of entities (i.e., table entities) into Azure data explorer cluster's database table using C# code?

for e.g.:
ADX cluster having database -> **Test** table.

```
public class TestEntity : ITableEntity
{ public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}

List<TestEntity> entities = new List<TestEntity>();
entities.Add(new TestEntity{ Id = 1, Name = "Test1" });
entities.Add(new TestEntity{ Id = 2, Name = "Test2" });
```

now I need to ingest this entities in ADX **Test** table.
My expected output as below,

ADX cluster -> TestDB -> **Test** table

```
+------+--------+
|  Id  |   Name |
+------+--------+
| 1    |  Test1 |
| 2    |  Test2 |
+------+--------+
```

Comment: Please try to clarify the question and provide a reproducible code.

Answer (score -1):

*Ingesting List of entities programatically using C# .Net in Azure Data*

*Create a storage account in Azure*
[image]

*Using the below code we can create tables and fetch the entities* And have to use the namespace
Using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table`

```
string mystrconnectionString = "ConnectionString";
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(mystrconnectionString);
        CloudTableClient tableClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Table Name to create");
        string tableName = Console.ReadLine();
        CloudTable cloudTable = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
        var result = tableClient.ListTables();
        int i = 1;
        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(i + " \t  " +item.Name);
                i++;
            }
        }
        CreateNewTable(cloudTable);

    if (!table.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table {0} already exists", table.Name);
                return;
            }
```

*The below are the tables created in azure using the code.*

[image]

*The list of tables fetched using the code*

[image]

The rows of the tables are fetched using the below code

```
TableQuery<Employee> tableQuery = new TableQuery<Employee>();
        foreach (Employee employeeEntity in table.ExecuteQuery(tableQuery))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee ID : {0}", employeeEntity.EmployeeID);
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Type : {0}", employeeEntity.EmployeeType);
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Name : {0}", employeeEntity.EmployeeName);
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Details : {0}", employeeEntity.EmployeeDetails);
            Console.WriteLine("******************************");
        }
```

[image]

**Update**

*And for **enlisting `Azure Data Explorer` programatically** we need to Install the below Nugets*

```
Microsoft.Azure.Management.kusto.
Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.
Microsoft.Azure.Management.EventGrid.
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.
Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication
```

*Code to fetch the table list and database list*

```
var Databse_And_tbl_Data = CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableRowStoreReferencesShowCommand(databaseName, tableName);
var  tbl_Data= CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableRowStoreReferencesShowCommand();
```

*For more information check this* [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/end-to-end-csharp)

Comment: Thank you. But, My query is regarding Azure Data Explorer where as you have given answer for Azure Table Storage.

Comment: *based on the text: for e.g.:* `ADX cluster having database -> Test table`.  *Provided the code for enlisting tables and data from the tables*

Comment: Thank you for the provided code to get list of tables data from Azure storage account. But, I've queried for Azure Data Explorer(i.e., ADX). FYI Azure Storage Account is different and Azure Data Explorer(i.e., ADX) is different.

Comment: *For Azure Data Explorer please check this* [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-overview#ingestion-methods)

Comment: Please check for the Update in the answer.